# java GroupLayout scrollbar

Tags: java, swing

Could someone please tell me how what and where I need to add something so that each area would have scroll bar?

I am trying to get a scrollbar for my text area but I'm failing all over again!

I created `GroupLayout` as you can see...

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.*;


import java.net.*;
import java.io.IOException;

public class GUIriks extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    JButton poga1 = new JButton("Poga 1"); //Definejam gui komponentes
    JTextArea area1 = new JTextArea(30,20); //Definejam gui komponentes
    JButton poga2 = new JButton("Poga 2"); //Definejam gui komponentes
    JTextArea area2 = new JTextArea(30,20); //Definejam gui komponentes
    JButton poga3 = new JButton("Poga 3"); //Definejam gui komponentes
    JTextArea area3 = new JTextArea(30,20); //Definejam gui komponentes
    JButton poga4 = new JButton("Poga 4"); //Definejam gui komponentes
    JTextArea area4 = new JTextArea(30,20); //Definejam gui komponentes



        public GUIriks(){
        super("GUI Rīks");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Container content = getContentPane();

            content.setBackground(Color.gray);

            GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(getContentPane());
            getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
            layout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
            layout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);

            content.add(poga1);
            content.add(area1);
            content.add(poga2);
            content.add(area2);
            content.add(poga3);
            content.add(area3);
            content.add(poga4);
            content.add(area4);


            JScrollPane scrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(area1);
            JScrollPane scrollPane2 = new JScrollPane(area2);
            JScrollPane scrollPane3 = new JScrollPane(area3);
            JScrollPane scrollPane4 = new JScrollPane(area4);
            content.add(scrollPane1, BorderLayout.WEST);
            content.add(scrollPane2, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            content.add(scrollPane3, BorderLayout.EAST);
            content.add(scrollPane4, BorderLayout.EAST);

            poga1.addActionListener(this);
            poga2.addActionListener(this);
            poga3.addActionListener(this);
            poga4.addActionListener(this);


            poga1.setBackground(new Color(175,238,238));
            poga2.setBackground(new Color(255,182,193));
            poga3.setBackground(new Color(211,211,211));
            poga4.setBackground(new Color(152,251,152));

            layout.setHorizontalGroup( layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup( layout.createParallelGroup( GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING )
                                           .addComponent( poga1 )
                                           .addComponent( poga2 )
                                           .addComponent( poga3 )
                                           .addComponent( poga4 ))
                        .addGroup( layout.createParallelGroup( GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING )
                                           .addComponent( area1 )
                                           .addComponent( area2 )
                                           .addComponent( area3 )
                                           .addComponent( area4 ))
    );

    // Vertically, we want to align each label with his textfield
    // on the baseline of the components
    layout.setVerticalGroup( layout.createSequentialGroup()
                      .addGroup( layout.createParallelGroup( GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE )
                                         .addComponent( poga1 )
                                         .addComponent( area1 ) )
                      .addGroup( layout.createParallelGroup( GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE )
                                         .addComponent( poga2 )
                                         .addComponent( area2 ) )
                      .addGroup( layout.createParallelGroup( GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE )
                                         .addComponent( poga3 )
                                         .addComponent( area3 ) )
                      .addGroup( layout.createParallelGroup( GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE )
                                         .addComponent( poga4 )
                                         .addComponent( area4 ) )
    );

            setSize(1000,400);
            setVisible(true);

        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {

            if (a.getSource() == poga1){

                this.metode1();}
            else if (a.getSource() == poga2){

                this.metode2();}
            else if (a.getSource() == poga3){

                this.metode3();}
            else if (a.getSource() == poga4){

                this.metode4();}
        }

        public void metode1()

        {
            try {
                InetAddress[] adreses = InetAddress.getAllByName("www.delfi.lv");
                for (int i = 0; i < adreses.length; i++) {
                    area1.append("Adresse ir:" + adreses[i] + "\n");
                }
                }
            catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
                area1.append("Nevaru atrastfind www.delfi.lv");
                }
        }

        public void metode2()

        {
            boolean rootaccess = false;
            for (int port = 1; port < 1024; port += 100) {
                try {
                    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(port);
                    // ja tas izdodas... tad...
                    rootaccess = true;
                    ss.close();
                    break;
                }
                catch (IOException ex) {
                }
            }
            int startport = 1;
            if (!rootaccess) startport = 1024;
            int stopport = 65535;
            for (int port = startport; port <= stopport; port++) {
                try {
                    ServerSocket socket1 = new ServerSocket(port);
                    socket1.close();
                }
                catch (IOException ex) {
                    area2.append("Ports " + port + " ir aiznemts \n");
                }
            }
            area2.append("Skenesana ir pabeigta!");
        }

        public void metode3()
        {
            Date sysDate = new Date();
            String dateString = sysDate.toString();
            area3.setText("Sodien ir " + dateString);
            area3.append("\n\n\n");
            area3.append("Seit var pievienot izvadu no citam metodem \n");
        }
        public void metode4()
        {
            try {
                InetAddress es = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
                area4.append("Mani sauc " + es.getHostName() + "\n");
                area4.append("Mana adrese ir " + es.getHostAddress() + "\n");
                byte[] adrese = es.getAddress();
                for (int i = 0; i < adrese.length; i++) {
                    area4.append(adrese[i] + " ");
                }

                }
            catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                area4.append("Nevaru noteikt lokalo adresi.");
                area4.append("Baidos ka tīks nestrādā...");
                }
        }
        public static void main(String[] args){
            new GUIriks();
        }

}
```

Comment: You set the layout manager as a `GroupLayout` but then use `BorderLayout` constraints?  Personally, I'd avoid `GroupLayout` it's not really meant for hand coding

Comment: Thanks for replay, but maybe you or someone else can show me? Is it so hard to add scroll bar here in my code?

Comment: No, it's not, but you need to understand what the rest of the code is doing.  You seem to be taking code you generated by a form editor and are then trying to modify it without actually knowing what the rest of the code is doing

Answer (score 2):

So, it's kind of hard to know exactly what you're doing, but my guess is you're taking code that was generated by a form editor and are trying to modify it to suit your new needs

But you're basic problem is, you're adding the `JTextArea`'s to the `content` panel, wrapping them in `JScrollPane`s, but then adding them back to the `content` pane via the layout ... which is just a mess.

Instead, your constructor should look like this...

```
content.add(poga1);
//content.add(area1);
content.add(poga2);
//content.add(area2);
content.add(poga3);
//content.add(area3);
content.add(poga4);
//content.add(area4);

JScrollPane scrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(area1);
JScrollPane scrollPane2 = new JScrollPane(area2);
JScrollPane scrollPane3 = new JScrollPane(area3);
JScrollPane scrollPane4 = new JScrollPane(area4);
content.add(scrollPane1, BorderLayout.WEST);
content.add(scrollPane2, BorderLayout.NORTH);
content.add(scrollPane3, BorderLayout.EAST);
content.add(scrollPane4, BorderLayout.EAST);

poga1.addActionListener(this);
poga2.addActionListener(this);
poga3.addActionListener(this);
poga4.addActionListener(this);

poga1.setBackground(new Color(175, 238, 238));
poga2.setBackground(new Color(255, 182, 193));
poga3.setBackground(new Color(211, 211, 211));
poga4.setBackground(new Color(152, 251, 152));

layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(poga1)
                .addComponent(poga2)
                .addComponent(poga3)
                .addComponent(poga4))
        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(scrollPane1)
                .addComponent(scrollPane2)
                .addComponent(scrollPane3)
                .addComponent(scrollPane4))
);

// Vertically, we want to align each label with his textfield
// on the baseline of the components
layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(poga1)
                .addComponent(scrollPane1))
        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(poga2)
                .addComponent(scrollPane2))
        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(poga3)
                .addComponent(scrollPane3))
        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(poga4)
                .addComponent(scrollPane4))
);
```